# I am getting __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'instance' with CreateView

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-views

I am using Django 2.1 version.
I am trying to make CreateView. Here is my views.py;

```
# views.py
class CreateJob(CreateView):
    form_class = CreateJob
    template_name = 'category_list.html'
```

and here is my forms.py;

```
# forms.py
from django import forms
from myapp.models import Category

class CreateJob(forms.Form):
    CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
    )
    category_list = forms.ChoiceField(
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={
            "id": "cate"
        }),
        choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES,
        required=True,
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CreateJob, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        category_choices = [(cat.id, cat.name) for cat in Category.objects.all()]
        self.fields['category_list'].choices = category_choices
```

in this forms.py I am trying to make choicefield and list category objects. and in my template, when i select category, it will make ajax request and will list description list which is related to Category model. you can look my template below. once I select one of categories which is created via choicefield in forms.py, it will list description list in option which has "desc" id.

```
{% extends '../base.html' %}

{% block body %}
   <form action="." method="post">
   {% csrf_token %}
   {{ form }}
   </form>

  <select id="desc">
    {% for description in description_list %}
      <option value="{{ description.pk }}">{{ description.name }}></option>
    {% endfor %}
  </select>
{% endblock %}

{% block script %}
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function (e) {
      $("#cate").change(function(e) {
        cat = $(this).val();
        var job = $("#desc");
        $.ajax({
          url: 'item/' + cat + '/',
          type: "GET",
          processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function (data) {
                  console.log(data.description_list),
                  job.html(data)
                },
                error: function (xhr, errmsg, err) {
                    console.log(xhr, errmsg, err);
                } // end error: function
            });
        });
    });
  </script>
{% endblock %}
```

and my urls.py is looks like this;

```
path('test/', CreateJob.as_view()),
```

when I proceed to 127.0.0.1:8000/test, it gives me this error:

```
File "C:\Users\kenan\Desktop\Django\jobs\myapp\forms.py", line 16, in __init__
super(CreateJob, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'instance'
[23/Aug/2018 14:37:03] "GET /test/ HTTP/1.1" 500 89443
```

> I want to note that, I searched for it and some people fix their problem by changing forms.Form to forms.ModelForm. but that's not what I want. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do here. Your view doesn't seem to have anything to do with creating anything; so why have you used a CreateView? Use a simple FormView.

Comment: Because I have not wrote it yet. I am just testing if it will list category objects or not.

Comment: But this makes no sense. If you want to use a view to create Job objects, use a CreateView with a ModelForm. If you want to return a list of Categories, which is something completely different, then don't use a CreateView.

Comment: right, I want to create Job object, but now when I change forms.Form to forms.ModelForm it gives me this error;

    `ValueError: ModelForm has no model class specified.`

Comment: ok, let me ask this way, how can i not write field in class Meta, but write my own custom fields?

Comment: In ModelForm as you say.

Comment: I'm still not understanding what problem you are having. Those two things are not in any way contradictory; you can use a ModelForm and still override the field.

Comment: ok I will try to write my problem again.
my models.py is this: [models.py](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/fPCdZGvvhM/)
in forms.py I want to to test that if I try to make Job object, it does work properly or not. I want to write my custom field, just one field to test will it get Description object when I select my Category Object.

Comment: But like I say, those are completely different things. I don't understand why you are trying to do the second thing in the view for the first thing. They literally have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: then what would you do, let's say if you want to create Job object and in the template you would like to list all the categories which if you select will make ajax request and list all it's descriptions

Comment: I would make a separate view for the Ajax request.

Comment: thanks for your patience. what I did not know was simple thing. I added category_list to fields in my forms.py and also changed to ModelForm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using a `CreateView` but the form you associate with it is not a `ModelForm`. `ModelForm` takes an optional `instance` arg (used for editing an existing model instance) - which is not a valid argument for non-model forms -, and `CreateView` passes this argument to your form class when instanciating it. Hence the error.

TL;DR : if you want to use a `CreateView`, you must use a `ModelForm` (or something that exposes the **exact same** API as a ModelForm).

Answer (score 1):

If you are just going to use a custom form and not a model form and generically construct the choices of the fields['category_list'] than you don't need to specify CategoryChoices() or the field. 
In the **init** you could just call the super() and then say

```
self.fields['category_list'] = forms.ChoiceField(
            choices=[(cat.id, cat.name) for cat in Category.objects.all()],
            required=False,
            )
```

OR you could just create a [modelchoicefield](https://docs.djangoproject.com/pl/2.1/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield) and declare the field like this:

```
field1 = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.all())
```